# Ext JS 3.2 Ext.namespace

Tags: extjs, namespaces

I cannot access objects using Ext.namespace().

Returns error TypeError: Company.Test is not a function

Been looking at the documentation but still unable use objects.

Here is namespace script

```
Ext.namespace('Company');
var Company = {

    Test: function(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }

};
```

And here is my script referencing the namespace

```
Ext.namespace('Company');
Ext.onReady(function(){

    console.clear();
    console.log('loading script');

    console.log('Namespace Function Test',Company.Test(2,5));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ext.namespace as described by the docs is:

> "used for scoping variables and classes so that they are not global.
>   Specifying the last node of a namespace implicitly creates all other
>   nodes".

So on your second block of code when you do a second `Ext.namespace('Company')` you are basically doing:

```
if (!Company) var Company = {};
```

I don't know from where in your code you are trying to get the Company object, but using `Ext.namespace` will not make it global, but if you want to create a global object you can create one using a singleton like:

```
Ext.define('Company', {
    singleton: true,
    Test: function(a,b) {
        return a + b;
    }
});
```